# Calling a server side function written in webparts using ajax call in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-parts

I am using the below javascript function to call a function placed in a webpart file in my solution using ajax.
Mainly, I am using webparts for my UI and controls are defined in the htm files and the webpart files load this htm files.

The below java script function is written in Pdf.htm file. and my AddRecord function is written in a PdfPart.cs, But its throwin the error. How do I check whats going wrong, the error is wat i have mentioned in the javascript function, alert("Record saved successfully in database");

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#OpenPdf").click(
    function () {
        //write a record in the table.
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          url: 'PdfPart.cs/AddRecord',
          //data: {'name': $('#txtname').val()},
          data: {'PdfId': PdfFullpaperlessModule},
          async: false,
          success: function (response) {
          alert("Record saved successfully in database");
          },
          error: function () {
          alert("some problem in saving data");
          }
  });    

                });
```

I Also have .aspx pages from which i direct it to the webparts.

Comment: can you mention the error from your console in FireBug?

Comment: umm, can you tell me how to check this?

Comment: I am using ie9 to debug my javascripts, is thr any way i can view it there ?

Comment: Go to the Settings tab and there at bottom you will see the developer tool. When you click on it at bottom of your window you will see the developer tool and there on second line you will see the Console click on it and you will be asked to reload the page just reload it Shown in red would be errors on the page